# Powershell Expiration Date calculating wrong days

Tags: powershell

good morning all,

I am stuck with an issue with the script created by Bradley Wyatt, it should be notifing users that their password is about to expire, but it has skipped a few users, as in these examples:

```
>C:\Users\> net user USER /domain
>Password expires             7/9/2021 8:20:25 AM
```

but in the script:

> 07/19/2021 08:00:02 - INFO: Password for USERNAME not expiring
> for 19 days

this is the mojo of the script:

```
$users = Get-Aduser -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress -filter { (Enabled -eq 'True') -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'False') } | Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpired -eq $False }

$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge

 #Get Password last set date
$passwordSetDate = (Get-ADUser $user -properties * | ForEach-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet })
#Check for Fine Grained Passwords
$PasswordPol = (Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null) {
    $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
}

$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
#Gets the count on how many days until the password expires and stores it in the $daystoexpire var
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days


If (($daystoexpire -ge "0") -and ($daystoexpire -lt $expireindays)) {
    "$Date - INFO: Sending expiry notice email to $Name" | Out-File ($DirPath + "\" + "Log.txt") -Append
    Write-Host "Sending Password expiry email to $name" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient
    $MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
```

can you guys get what am I missing?

Comment: Different DC's. Net User pulls from one of the DC's (*not sure how it dictates it - unless it's using the one you're on - then I'm not sure how `Get-ADUser` does.*). You would have to query each DC for the information, and grab the latest one. It's a duplication delay between DCs.

Comment: Fine grained password policy? See: [Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adfinegrainedpasswordpolicy)

Comment: As aside, you should also look at attribute `PasswordNotRequired`. If that is $true, you can skip that user, same as when `PasswordNeverExpires` is $true. Oh yeah.. `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, that couldnt be, I was running the snippet within the affected DC and we have only two with zero delay for replication

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble team, but one of my colleagues that has a quick hand changed the max password age in the DC without reporting me. thanks

> Enforce password history 5 passwords remembered
> **Maximum password age 60 days**  Minimum password age 5 days  Minimum password length 14 characters  Password must meet complexity
> requirements Enabled  Store passwords using reversible encryption
> Disabled

Comment: Aha! I was close!